# Python script with cron

Tags: python, cron

Newbie question! :)

I'm try to running every minute a simple python app with cron: the code works it is a simple hello world example :)

```
/etc# python greeting.py
```

hello finally!

This is the crontab:

```
* * * * * python /etc/greeting.py
```

Then I restarted cron with
`/etc/init.d/cron restart` but nothing happens.

Thank you

Comment: you should specify full path for python like /usr/bin/python

Comment: What is the script supposed to be doing? If you're expecting it to print to the console, it won't; the output will be in a log file.

Comment: Yes, I tought it will print to the console.
So do I have to specify the output file also?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory where `python` is installed in your system:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/which python
/home/mayankp/bin/python
```

Then, pass this whole path in `crontab`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This way: * * * * * usr/bin/ python /etc/greeting.py  ?

Thanks